Any better way to improve the code to keep the underlying memory blocks used by aiso::async_send remains valid
I once wrote the the code snippet below to asynchronously send tcp data.
void Conversation::do_write(std::string str)
{
  auto conversation_ptr(shared_from_this());
  m_socket.async_send(asio::buffer(str), [this, conversation_ptr](std::error_code error, size_t length ){
    if (!error)
    {
        std::cout << "data write successfully" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "error in writing data: " << error.message() << std::endl;
    }
  });
}

Later, I found there is something wrong with the code above though nobody pointed it out before. As per the documentation, which says that the underlying memory blocks are retained by the caller, which must guarantee that they remain valid until the handler is called.

basic_stream_socket::async_send (1 of 2 overloads)
Start an asynchronous send.
 template<
     typename ConstBufferSequence,
     typename WriteToken = default_completion_token_t<executor_type>>
 DEDUCED async_send(
     const ConstBufferSequence & buffers,
     WriteToken && token = default_completion_token_t< executor_type >());

This function is used to asynchronously send data on the stream socket. It is an initiating function for an asynchronous operation, and always returns immediately.
Parameters

buffers
One or more data buffers to be sent on the socket. Although the buffers object may be copied as necessary, ownership of the underlying memory blocks is retained by the caller, which must guarantee that they remain valid until the completion handler is called.



To keep the context alive, I rewrite the code as blow.
//Note: the passed string would be modified to avoid copying
void Conversation::do_write(std::string& str)  //modification1: using the reference
{
    auto conversation_ptr(shared_from_this());
    //modification2 using shared pointer to keep the content to be sent alive when the handler is called
    std::shared_ptr<std::string> content_ptr=std::make_shared<std::string>(std::move(str));
    m_socket.async_send(asio::buffer(*content_ptr), [this, conversation_ptr, content_ptr](std::error_code error, size_t length ){
    if (!error)
    {
        std::cout << "data write successfully" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "error in writing data: " << error.message() << std::endl;
    }
  });
}

Is there any better way? How do I improve the code above?

Always run with sanitizers to avoid losing a lot of money on bugs like that. It's a very very common beginner pitfall. I think your linked question simply never got any Asio experienced eyes on it. I suggest [tag:boost-asio] which has an order of magnitude more traffic than [tag:asio]

@sehe Thank you for advice. I get it. But it seems there is  something wrong with sanitizers. See the SO created day ago for details.

What you did works. However, I'd take str by value, since you're "sinking" its data. Let the caller decide whether the side-effect of clearing the argument's value is desired.
std::string message = "Hello\n";
psession1->do_write(message); // copy
psession2->do_write(std::move(message)); // move

Next up, it's more customary to make the data member of the class, since the class that contains the socket already has to guarantee the correct life-time anyways.

Your Conversation class may already inherit from std::enable_shared_from_this for the purpose of guaranteeing the lifetime, no need to duplicate the effort for any extra state

To top it all off: in many situations you have to watch for concurrent write requests anyways, and you will have a member like std::deque<std::string> instead to keep track of pending writes.
That way you ensure reference stability of the buffers involved, can avoid overlapping write operations and unnecessary dynamic allocation and reference-counting.
For examples of this you can scan any of my Asio answers for such queues, just picking the first that I see: How to safely write to a socket from multiple threads?

Thank you for the reply. I fully understand why you choose to pass std::string other than std::string& as the parameter now. Another question arises, which one is better, void Conversation::do_write(std::string str) or void Conversation::do_write(std::shared_ptr<std::string> content)?

You said that it's more customary to make the data member of the class. If I undertand you correctly, you mean creating a buffer as member variable of Conversation class is commonly seen. Why I don't want do that? Because I want to decouple the message proccessing and replying with the implementation of the class of Conversation.Say, there is worker thread who processes the coming message and replys them.

Re1: if you ask that, I will say you didn't fully understand why I pass the string by value. Passing by shared pointer mandates 1 or two dynamic allocations. I could maybe see shared_ptr<std::string const> in an application where the same message gets sent to many clients or many times? Passing by value is obviously more flexible in all other ways. E.g. If you somehow hold the shared pointer (unlikely) you could still trivially pass it as std::move(*pmsg). The inverse is not true. Tears when do_write("Hello\n") needs to become do_write(std::make_shared<std::string>("Hello\n"))...

Re2: @John That's ... completely orthogonal. You can decouple the message processing, however your conversation class is the sole responsible entity for the buffers used in its transport operations. Moving them into the members makes it very lightweight. It doesn't matter where the message comes from. You just "adopt" it, and say "I'll make sure it gets delivered, thank you"

For Re1, I see. thank you for the detailed exaplanation. For Re2, I have read your comment serveral times to bettter understand it. I thought and thought about how to make the buffers as members. Maybe, a queue(i.e. std::queue<std::string> Consersation::to_be_sent_queue or sth alike) is needed. You see the sending messages are asynchronous and many message may be pended. Here is the code snippet which achieve that goal  (search UPDATE1: make the write buffers as member variables. as the keyword). Note do_write is used in other thread in practice.

It seems my last comment is right. I re-read your answer again and find you have said the similar statement already. It's 6:00 am, forgive my foolish. :(
